# Why does my wordle logic give the wrong result when the character in the guess is repeated too many times?

Tags: python, wordle-game

Following the principles of wordle, each guess is checked and a five letter output is given. G represents green for letters that are the same and in the right place, yellow for letters that the same in the wrong place, and B for no matches.

```
def output_guess(guess:str, word: str, dictionary: list):
    """
        Checks guess for game errors, and outputs current "score" to user
        parameters: user's guess, word from dictionary, dictionary
        return: none
    """
    output = ""
    if len(guess) == 5 and guess in dictionary:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess[i] == word[i]:
                output += "G"
            elif guess[i] in word:
                output += "Y"
            else:
                output += "B"
    else:
        print("Word not found in dictionary. Enter a five-letter english word.", end = "")
    print(output)
```

If the answer for example were the five letter word eerie, I would want to receive these outputs for the following guesses:

```
Guess 1: epees  GBYYB
Guess 2: peeve  BGYBG
Guess 3: order  BYBYB
Guess 4: eerie  GGGGG
```

All of my guesses for my code receive the correct output aside from Guess 3. For Guess 3: order, I get BYBYY instead of BYBYB.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) What is `guess[i] in word` for the last character in `order`?

Comment: Right now your algorithm is that if the letter is in the target word anywhere, but not at the current position, output "Y", but you need to keep track of the number of occurrences to not show too many "Y"s.

Comment: You have the issue because you don't differentiate between letters that have previously already been tested. The last r in order is tested as r in word - which it is, and so you get true. You need to add additional code for cases where a letter appears multiple times in a guess but  only appears once in the word. You also need to make it more generic to cope with a letter appearing three times in guess but only twice in word.

Comment: I don't understand. **Why is this output wrong**? when `ORDER` is guessed, the last `R` corresponds to a letter *that is in* the secret word `EERIE`, but not at that position. So why should the output say `B`? I think it should say `Y`, exactly like the program does.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect. It is not sufficient to check simply that the character exists in the word, you also need to *count* the characters in the input and make sure there are an equal or smaller number in the word

```
import collections

word = "eerie"
guess = "order"

word_counts = collections.Counter(word)     # Count characters in the word
guess_counts = collections.defaultdict(int) # Create an empty dict to count characters in guess
output = []
for g, w in zip(guess, word):
    guess_counts[g] += 1 # Add to count of current character
    if g == w:
        # Correct character, correct position
        output += "G"
    elif guess_counts[g] <= word_counts[g]:
        # The minimum that `guess_counts[g]` can be is 1 
        # Why? We set it in the first line of this loop
        # For this condition to be true, word_counts[g] must be > 0
        #      (i.e `word` must contain `g`)
        # And we must have seen `g` fewer (or equal) times than
        # the word contains `g`
        output += "Y"
    else:
        output += "B"
        
print(output)
```

I used [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of manually counting the letters, and [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) so I don't need to check if the dict contains the character before incrementing it.